# Java determining array size in an unknown array via reflection

Tags: java, reflection

This one is going to be tough to explain but I'll give it a shot. I am trying to dynamically create a database table that mimics java objects. So it will have each column for each defined field in a particular object. These java objects can have defined primitives, arrays and other objects inside them. I am generating the SQLite create statement from a recursive function I created. More specifically this function will create the column/type pairs in the DB create table query.

The issue I run into is trying to determine array an array size. Here is my function that generates the column/type pairs.

```
public String processColumnData(String topicName)
{
    Field fieldList[] = null;
    String query = "";

    try
    {
        fieldList = Class.forName(topicName).getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field a : fieldList)
        {
            if ((a.getType().getName().equals("int")) || (a.getType().getName().equals("long")) || (a.getType().getName().equals("short")) || (a.getType().getName().equals("byte"))
                    || (a.getType().getName().equals("boolean")) || (com.rti.dds.util.Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(a.getType())))
            {
                query = query + "'" + a.getName() + "'" + " INTEGER,";
            } else if (a.getType().getName().equals("java.lang.String"))
            {
                query = query + "'" + a.getName() + "'" + " TEXT,";
            } else if (a.getType().getName().equals("float"))
            {
                query = query + "'" + a.getName() + "'" + " REAL,";
            } else if (a.getType().isArray() && ((a.getType().getName().startsWith("["))))
            {
                if (a.getType().getName().equals("[F"))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Array.getLength(a.get(Class.forName(topicName))); i++)
                    {
                        query = query + "'" + a.getName() + "[" + i + "]' REAL,";
                    }
                } else if ((a.getType().getName().equals("[Ljava.lang.String;")))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Array.getLength(a.get(Class.forName(topicName))); i++)
                    {
                        query = query + "'" + a.getName() + "[" + i + "]' TEXT,";
                    }
                } else if (a.getType().getName().equals("[I") || a.getType().getName().equals("[S") || a.getType().getName().equals("[B")
                        || (com.rti.dds.util.Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(Class.forName(a.getType().getName().replace(";", "").replace("[L", "")))))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Array.getLength(a.get(Class.forName(topicName))); i++)
                    {
                        query = query + "'" + a.getName() + "[" + i + "]' INTEGER,";
                    }
                } else
                {
                    // TODO: Arrays of objects not enums.
                }
            } else
            {
                processColumnData(a.getType().getName());
            }

        }
    } catch (SecurityException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Security Exception");
        return null;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Class not found " + topicName);
        return null;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(query);
    return query;
}
```

The primitives are straight to the point but when I get to arrays, it will not let me determine the size. I know that I should be passing in an instance of the class to the get() instead of the class itself but I do not currently have an instance. Below is an example of an object with an array that can come into the above function:

```
public class jOverLoad   implements Copyable, Serializable{

public int machineId= 0;
public int motorIndex= 0;
public int motorDescriptionTidx= 0;
public jTimeType timeOfLastThermalTrip = (jTimeType)jTimeType.create();
public float thermalTimer= 0;
public boolean thermalWarning= false;
public boolean thermalTrip= false;
public boolean jamWarning= false;
public boolean jamTrip= false;
public int jamResetTimer= 0;
public float phaseImbalance= 0;
public boolean phaseImbalanceTrip= false;
public boolean phaseAOK= false;
public boolean phaseBOK= false;
public boolean phaseCOK= false;
public jRtdStatus [] rtdTripStatus=  new jRtdStatus [(J_MAX_MOTOR_RTDS.VALUE)];
```

I figured since the size is defined in the instantiation of the array, I should somehow be able to get that value. Is there a way?

Comment: Length is not a property of array types.  Only array *instances* have lengths.

Comment: I know, but since it's instantiated at the top of the class as it is... is it not already an instance in the Class? - PS I'm on a limb here.

Comment: My humble advice: serialize (as json?) and store as text in your DB

Comment: No, it isn't.  The class's bytecode contains code to instantiate an array and assign it to the field during instance initialization.  Each instance gets its own, and the class itself has none.  In principle, the data you want is thus buried in the class, but you cannot access it reflectively.

Comment: I'm trying to mimic the database of our RTI DDS Recorder. It is able to do this but I think it is written in C. The original instantiation  written:    jRtdStatus       rtdTripStatus[J_MAX_MOTOR_RTDS];

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#getLength(java.lang.Object)

Comment: This code is *horrible*. There is no need to mess around with the *names* of the types. Use the *types*, e.g. `Class<?> type = a.getType(); if(type==int.class || type==long.class || type==short.class) … … else if(type.isArray()) { Class<?> ct = type.getComponentType();  if(ct==int.class) … else if(ct==String.class) … } …`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did to resolve this was to create a faux instance of the object by:

```
Class.forName(topicName).getConstructor().newInstance()
```

and I passed that into the a.get() to find array length.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the getter isArray for Class class:

```
    Integer[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    Object obj = array;

    int lenght;

    if(obj.getClass().isArray()){
        lenght = (Integer)obj.getClass().getField("lenght").get(obj);
    }
```

Comment: That's an instance of an array. I only have the class object where I know one of the fields are an array.

Comment: `NoSuchFieldException: lenght` --- Even fixing typ: `NoSuchFieldException: length`